# Apache is serving SSL when its not in the vhost configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, debian-buster

We have multiple sites in our apache configuration.
All of these sites are defined in their own vhost.
However we have a site that is served on SSL when it is not defined in our VHOSTS:
Here is the output of apachectl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server a.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/a.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost a.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/a.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias a.com,www2.a.com,a.com,www.a.com
         port 443 namevhost az.h.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/az.h-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias az.h.com
                 alias az.h.com
         port 443 namevhost b.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/s.e-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias b.com
         port 443 namevhost www.c.com,www2.c.com,c.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/c.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias c.com
         port 443 namevhost d.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/d-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias www.d.com
         port 443 namevhost e.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/e-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias e.com
                 alias www.e.com
         port 443 namevhost www.e.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/e-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias e.com
         port 443 namevhost f.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/f-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias f.com
                 alias www.f.com
         port 443 namevhost www.g.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/g-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias g.com
         port 443 namevhost www.h.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/h-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias h.com
                 wild alias *.h.com
         port 443 namevhost truck.i.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/truck.i-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias truck.i.com
         port 443 namevhost i.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/i-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias i.com
                 alias www.i.com
         port 443 namevhost www.j.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/j-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias j.com
         port 443 namevhost www.k.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/k-ssl.conf:1)
                 alias k.com
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server a.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/a.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost a.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/a.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.a.com,www2.a.com,a.com
         port 80 namevhost www.c.com,www2.c.com,c.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/c.com.conf:1)
                 alias c.com
         port 80 namevhost www.d.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/d.conf:1)
                 alias d.com
         port 80 namevhost www.x.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/x.conf:1)
                 alias x.com
         port 80 namevhost www.e.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/e.conf:1)
                 alias e.com
         port 80 namevhost www.e.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/e.conf:1)
                 alias e.com
         port 80 namevhost www.g.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/g.conf:1)
                 alias g.com
         port 80 namevhost www.z.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/z.conf:1)
                 alias z.com
         port 80 namevhost www.h.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/h.conf:1)
                 alias h.com
                 wild alias *.h.com
         port 80 namevhost www.i.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/i.conf:1)
                 alias i.com
         port 80 namevhost www.j.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/j.conf:1)
                 alias j.com
         port 80 namevhost www.k.com.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/k.conf:1)
                 alias k.com
```

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: so for namevhost www.z.com is only served on port 80 but is serving ssl requests on port 443 and I cant figure out why.

Comment: Because you have a web server on port 443. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want it to only serve on port 80 not 443 its displaying a site with an invalid cert it is displaying a ssl site with a.com's cert.

Comment: Hmm so enabling ssl on that site would fix the security problem thanks. I'll try it out.